# get index of jquery element after event has fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm creating video objects via jquery from an array of urls that point to mp4 files. 
I want to have the first video autoplay then once its finished pick up on the "ended" function and play the next video in the sequence.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var urls = ["https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/linkto.mp4", "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/linktoother.mp4"]
            var videos = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

                var path = urls[i];

                var video = $('<video></video>');
                var source = $('<source></source>');

                source.attr('src', path);
                source.appendTo(video);

                if (i === 0) {
                    video.attr('autoplay', 'true');
                }
                video.attr('id', 'video_' + i);
                video.attr('preload', 'true');
                video.attr('width', '100%');

                videos.push(video);

                video.on('ended', function () {
                    console.log('Video has ended!' + i);
//                        playNext(video);
                });

                $('#movie').append(video);

            }
```

I can see the movies generated and the first one plays fine. The problem is when 'ended' function the variable i == 2 because thats how many videos are in the array and the for loop increased i. I've been away from javascript for a while. I can think of workarounds like adding an index attribute to the video element or something but basically how do I get the correct index in the "ended" function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the wrong use of a closure variable in a loop.

In your case you can create a local closure by using $.each() to iterate over the array

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var urls = ["https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/linkto.mp4", "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/linktoother.mp4"]
    var videos = [];

    $.each(urls, function (i, path) {
        var video = $('<video></video>');
        var source = $('<source></source>');

        source.attr('src', path);
        source.appendTo(video);

        if (i === 0) {
            video.attr('autoplay', 'true');
        }
        video.attr('id', 'video_' + i);
        video.attr('preload', 'true');
        video.attr('width', '100%');

        videos.push(video);

        video.on('ended', function () {
            console.log(i)
        });

        $('#movie').append(video);
    })

})
```

---

You really don't want to have the index, since all the video elements are siblings you can just find the next sibling of the currently ended video element

```
    video.on('ended', function () {
        console.log('Video has ended!' + $(this).index());
        var $current = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();
        console.log($next.find('source').attr('src'))
        //playNext($(this));
    });
```

- [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake)
- [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: thanks that is a better solution!, very minor error fixed as well